# enable child control while Custom parent is disabled in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Hello I made custom made parent control for zooming Picture  . Inside That Control there is child canvas and inside Canvas There is child image Control . And I created A menu for Zoom and Image measuring . I also can able to measure co Ordinates the image . My problem when I disabled Parent ZoomBorder control I cannot triggering event of Child Image .  I can disable ZoomControl named ZoomBorder but I want image event of MouseDown . I can Disable child Image event when Zoomcontrol enabled and It works.
Here is my code .

```
<utils:ZoomBorder x:Name="ZoomBorder"   IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableZoom}"   ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gray" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <Canvas IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableCanvas}">
            <Image  x:Name="DIIMGFINAL" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action MDownCalCulateDistance($source, $eventArgs)];
                [Event MouseUp] = [Action MUpCalCulateDistance($source, $eventArgs)];
                [Event MouseMove] = [Action MMoveCalCulateDistance($source, $eventArgs)]"/>
            <Line IsHitTestVisible="False"  X1="{Binding FirstPoint.X}" Y1="{Binding FirstPoint.Y}"
                  X2="{Binding SecondPoint.X}" Y2="{Binding SecondPoint.Y}"
                  Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3"/>
        </Canvas>
    </utils:ZoomBorder>
```

And Here is The Menu Item ImageMeasuring and Zoom

```
<Menu Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Background="Transparent" >
        <MenuItem x:Name="ズームControl" Header="ズーム">
            <!--Item For Zoom-->
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem x:Name="Img_Measurement" Header="Image Measurement">
            <!--Item For Measure-->
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Here is My C# code For Zoom Activation

```
  public void ズームControl()
    {
        //For Only Zoom
        IsEnableZoom = true;
        IsEnableCanvas = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Zoom Control Starts", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    }
```

Here Is Image Measurement

```
 public void Img_Measurement()
    {
        IsEnableZoom = false;
        IsEnableCanvas = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Image Measurement Starts", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    }
```

Here Is My Image MouseDown Event

```
public void MDownCalCulateDistance(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         f (IsEnableCanvas == false) return;

        if (!(sender is System.Windows.Controls.Image)) return;
        try{
            //Code Here
        }
        Catch(Exception ex){
            //code here
        }
    }
```

And Here is Property For Enabling

```
 public bool IsEnableZoom
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEnableZoom;
        }
        set
        {

            _isEnableZoom = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsEnableZoom);
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnableCanvas
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEnableCanvas;
        }
        set
        {

            _isEnableCanvas = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsEnableCanvas);
        }
    }
```

As You can See When I disbled the ZoomBorder of ZoomControl I cannot go The MouseDown Event . I can Mousedown disbled when ZoomBorder of Parent event enabled . Please Help me . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Disabled elements don't raise mouse events. This is by design.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.isenabled?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077):

> Elements that are not enabled do not participate in hit testing or focus and therefore will not be sources of input events.

The obvious solution is not to disable the `Canvas`. You may still make it look and/or behave like it was disabled.

Comment: I want To raise Event when parent control disabled but child control enabled . Then . Can it possible

Comment: When you disable the `Canvas`, its children are disabled as well. So the child control isn't enabled.

Comment: But I want to enable child Control Can it possible ....

Comment: No, you cannot enable a child control of a disabled `Canvas`.