# Inside Parent Control ChildControl Event in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Hello I have question of Parent Control and Child Control . I want to access child control Event works . I have a class name Zoom Border for Zoom Control Inside I Have image . I have found a problem like  [enable child control while Custom parent is disabled in wpf C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029418/enable-child-control-while-custom-parent-is-disabled-in-wpf-c-sharp) but that is not I wanted . I want when I zoom In after a button click i want to access child Image control . here is the code

```
 <utils:ZoomBorder x:Name="ZoomBorder" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsDiIMGVisible, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"   IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableZoom}"   ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gray" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
       
            <Image   x:Name="DIIMGFINAL"  />

    </utils:ZoomBorder>
```

After certain condition like button click I want to access Image MouseDown Mouse Up Event . Can it possible .

Comment: Use Binding to [`IsMouseDirectlyOver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ismousedirectlyover?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_UIElement_IsMouseDirectlyOver) property instead.

Comment: Should I Use in zoomBorder